# Why a for cycle in a django template add space at the end of my tag?

Tags: django, django-taggit

My `template.html`:

```
{% for x in post.tags.all %}
  <a href="{% url 'blog:post_list_by_tag' x.slug %}">
    {{ x.name }}
  </a>
  {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I haven't space at the end of the lines and I haven't space in the name (in database) but the output is:

```
tag1 , tag2 , tag3
```

with a space between name and comma and a space at the end. Even with one tag there's a space at the end. I use taggit, maybe the problem is there.

Also the links underline even the white spaces when after there's the comma (so not at the end). If I write `{{ x.name }}</a>` the spaces are there but the links underline only the tags, not the spaces.

In myview

`print(post.tags)` => `AttributeError: '_TaggableManager' object has no attribute 'name'`

`print(post.tags.all)` =>

```
<bound method BaseManager.all of <taggit.managers._TaggableManager object at 0x03EFEA70>>
```

Mymodel.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, 
        on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_('autore'))
    title = models.CharField(_('titolo'), max_length=32)
    text = models.TextField(_('testo'))
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(_('creato il'),
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(_('pubblicato il'),
            blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='posts_liked', blank=True, verbose_name=_('piace a'))
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='posts_disliked', blank=True, verbose_name=_('non piace a'))
    tags = TaggableManager()
    views = models.IntegerField(_('visite'), default=0)
    block_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = pgettext('singolare', 'post')
        verbose_name_plural = pgettext('plurale', 'post')

...
```

taggit.managers.py:

```
...
class _TaggableManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, through, model, instance, prefetch_cache_name):
        self.through = through
        self.model = model
        self.instance = instance
        self.prefetch_cache_name = prefetch_cache_name
        self._db = None

    def is_cached(self, instance):
        return self.prefetch_cache_name in instance._prefetched_objects_cache

    def get_queryset(self, extra_filters=None):
        try:
            return self.instance._prefetched_objects_cache[self.prefetch_cache_name]
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            kwargs = extra_filters if extra_filters else {}
            return self.through.tags_for(self.model, self.instance, **kwargs)

    def get_prefetch_queryset(self, instances, queryset=None):
        if queryset is not None:
            raise ValueError("Custom queryset can't be used for this lookup.")

        instance = instances[0]
        from django.db import connections
        db = self._db or router.db_for_read(instance.__class__, instance=instance)

        fieldname = ('object_id' if issubclass(self.through, CommonGenericTaggedItemBase)
                     else 'content_object')
        fk = self.through._meta.get_field(fieldname)
        query = {
            '%s__%s__in' % (self.through.tag_relname(), fk.name):
                set(obj._get_pk_val() for obj in instances)
        }
        join_table = self.through._meta.db_table
        source_col = fk.column
        connection = connections[db]
        qn = connection.ops.quote_name
        qs = self.get_queryset(query).using(db).extra(
            select={
                '_prefetch_related_val': '%s.%s' % (qn(join_table), qn(source_col))
            }
        )
        return (qs,
                attrgetter('_prefetch_related_val'),
                lambda obj: obj._get_pk_val(),
                False,
                self.prefetch_cache_name)

    # Django < 1.6 uses the previous name of query_set
    get_query_set = get_queryset
    get_prefetch_query_set = get_prefetch_queryset

    def _lookup_kwargs(self):
        return self.through.lookup_kwargs(self.instance)

    @require_instance_manager
    def add(self, *tags):
        db = router.db_for_write(self.through, instance=self.instance)

        tag_objs = self._to_tag_model_instances(tags)
        new_ids = set(t.pk for t in tag_objs)

        # NOTE: can we hardcode 'tag_id' here or should the column name be got
        # dynamically from somewhere?
        vals = (self.through._default_manager.using(db)
                .values_list('tag_id', flat=True)
                .filter(**self._lookup_kwargs()))

        new_ids = new_ids - set(vals)

        signals.m2m_changed.send(
            sender=self.through, action="pre_add",
            instance=self.instance, reverse=False,
            model=self.through.tag_model(), pk_set=new_ids, using=db,
        )

        for tag in tag_objs:
            self.through._default_manager.using(db).get_or_create(
                tag=tag, **self._lookup_kwargs())

        signals.m2m_changed.send(
            sender=self.through, action="post_add",
            instance=self.instance, reverse=False,
            model=self.through.tag_model(), pk_set=new_ids, using=db,
        )

    def _to_tag_model_instances(self, tags):
        """
        Takes an iterable containing either strings, tag objects, or a mixture
        of both and returns set of tag objects.
        """
        db = router.db_for_write(self.through, instance=self.instance)

        str_tags = set()
        tag_objs = set()

        for t in tags:
            if isinstance(t, self.through.tag_model()):
                tag_objs.add(t)
            elif isinstance(t, six.string_types):
                str_tags.add(t)
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Cannot add {0} ({1}). Expected {2} or str.".format(
                        t, type(t), type(self.through.tag_model())))

        if getattr(settings, 'TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE', False):
            # Some databases can do case-insensitive comparison with IN, which
            # would be faster, but we can't rely on it or easily detect it.
            existing = []
            tags_to_create = []

            for name in str_tags:
                try:
                    tag = (self.through.tag_model()._default_manager
                           .using(db)
                           .get(name__iexact=name))
                    existing.append(tag)
                except self.through.tag_model().DoesNotExist:
                    tags_to_create.append(name)
        else:
            # If str_tags has 0 elements Django actually optimizes that to not
            # do a query.  Malcolm is very smart.
            existing = (self.through.tag_model()._default_manager
                        .using(db)
                        .filter(name__in=str_tags))

            tags_to_create = str_tags - set(t.name for t in existing)

        tag_objs.update(existing)

        for new_tag in tags_to_create:
            tag_objs.add(
                self.through.tag_model()._default_manager
                .using(db)
                .create(name=new_tag))

        return tag_objs

    @require_instance_manager
    def names(self):
        return self.get_queryset().values_list('name', flat=True)

    @require_instance_manager
    def slugs(self):
        return self.get_queryset().values_list('slug', flat=True)

    @require_instance_manager
    def set(self, *tags, **kwargs):
        """
        Set the object's tags to the given n tags. If the clear kwarg is True
        then all existing tags are removed (using `.clear()`) and the new tags
        added. Otherwise, only those tags that are not present in the args are
        removed and any new tags added.
        """
        db = router.db_for_write(self.through, instance=self.instance)
        clear = kwargs.pop('clear', False)

        if clear:
            self.clear()
            self.add(*tags)
        else:
            # make sure we're working with a collection of a uniform type
            objs = self._to_tag_model_instances(tags)

            # get the existing tag strings
            old_tag_strs = set(self.through._default_manager
                               .using(db)
                               .filter(**self._lookup_kwargs())
                               .values_list('tag__name', flat=True))

            new_objs = []
            for obj in objs:
                if obj.name in old_tag_strs:
                    old_tag_strs.remove(obj.name)
                else:
                    new_objs.append(obj)

            self.remove(*old_tag_strs)
            self.add(*new_objs)

    @require_instance_manager
    def remove(self, *tags):
        if not tags:
            return

        db = router.db_for_write(self.through, instance=self.instance)

        qs = (self.through._default_manager.using(db)
              .filter(**self._lookup_kwargs())
              .filter(tag__name__in=tags))

        old_ids = set(qs.values_list('tag_id', flat=True))

        signals.m2m_changed.send(
            sender=self.through, action="pre_remove",
            instance=self.instance, reverse=False,
            model=self.through.tag_model(), pk_set=old_ids, using=db,
        )
        qs.delete()
        signals.m2m_changed.send(
            sender=self.through, action="post_remove",
            instance=self.instance, reverse=False,
            model=self.through.tag_model(), pk_set=old_ids, using=db,
        )

    @require_instance_manager
    def clear(self):
        db = router.db_for_write(self.through, instance=self.instance)

        signals.m2m_changed.send(
            sender=self.through, action="pre_clear",
            instance=self.instance, reverse=False,
            model=self.through.tag_model(), pk_set=None, using=db,
        )

        self.through._default_manager.using(db).filter(
            **self._lookup_kwargs()).delete()

        signals.m2m_changed.send(
            sender=self.through, action="post_clear",
            instance=self.instance, reverse=False,
            model=self.through.tag_model(), pk_set=None, using=db,
        )

    def most_common(self, min_count=None, extra_filters=None):
        queryset = self.get_queryset(extra_filters).annotate(
            num_times=models.Count(self.through.tag_relname())
        ).order_by('-num_times')
        if min_count:
            queryset = queryset.filter(num_times__gte=min_count)

        return queryset

    @require_instance_manager
    def similar_objects(self):
        lookup_kwargs = self._lookup_kwargs()
        lookup_keys = sorted(lookup_kwargs)
        qs = self.through.objects.values(*six.iterkeys(lookup_kwargs))
        qs = qs.annotate(n=models.Count('pk'))
        qs = qs.exclude(**lookup_kwargs)
        qs = qs.filter(tag__in=self.all())
        qs = qs.order_by('-n')

        # TODO: This all feels like a bit of a hack.
        items = {}
        if len(lookup_keys) == 1:
            # Can we do this without a second query by using a select_related()
            # somehow?
            f = _get_field(self.through, lookup_keys[0])
            remote_field = _remote_field(f)
            rel_model = _related_model(_remote_field(f))
            objs = rel_model._default_manager.filter(**{
                "%s__in" % remote_field.field_name: [r["content_object"] for r in qs]
            })
            for obj in objs:
                items[(getattr(obj, remote_field.field_name),)] = obj
        else:
            preload = {}
            for result in qs:
                preload.setdefault(result['content_type'], set())
                preload[result["content_type"]].add(result["object_id"])

            for ct, obj_ids in preload.items():
                ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_id(ct)
                for obj in ct.model_class()._default_manager.filter(pk__in=obj_ids):
                    items[(ct.pk, obj.pk)] = obj

        results = []
        for result in qs:
            obj = items[
                tuple(result[k] for k in lookup_keys)
            ]
            obj.similar_tags = result["n"]
            results.append(obj)
        return results

    # _TaggableManager needs to be hashable but BaseManagers in Django 1.8+ overrides
    # the __eq__ method which makes the default __hash__ method disappear.
    # This checks if the __hash__ attribute is None, and if so, it reinstates the original method.
    if models.Manager.__hash__ is None:
        __hash__ = object.__hash__


class TaggableManager(RelatedField, Field):
    # Field flags
    many_to_many = True
    many_to_one = False
    one_to_many = False
    one_to_one = False

    _related_name_counter = 0

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=_("Tags"),
                 help_text=_("A comma-separated list of tags."),
                 through=None, blank=False, related_name=None, to=None,
                 manager=_TaggableManager):

        self.through = through or TaggedItem
        self.swappable = False
        self.manager = manager

        rel = TaggableRel(self, related_name, self.through, to=to)

        Field.__init__(
            self,
            verbose_name=verbose_name,
            help_text=help_text,
            blank=blank,
            null=True,
            serialize=False,
            rel=rel,
        )
        # NOTE: `to` is ignored, only used via `deconstruct`.

    def __get__(self, instance, model):
        if instance is not None and instance.pk is None:
            raise ValueError("%s objects need to have a primary key value "
                             "before you can access their tags." % model.__name__)
        manager = self.manager(
            through=self.through,
            model=model,
            instance=instance,
            prefetch_cache_name=self.name
        )
        return manager

    def deconstruct(self):
        """
        Deconstruct the object, used with migrations.
        """
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(TaggableManager, self).deconstruct()
        # Remove forced kwargs.
        for kwarg in ('serialize', 'null'):
            del kwargs[kwarg]
        # Add arguments related to relations.
        # Ref: https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/issues/206#issuecomment-37578676
        rel = _remote_field(self)
        if isinstance(rel.through, six.string_types):
            kwargs['through'] = rel.through
        elif not rel.through._meta.auto_created:
            kwargs['through'] = "%s.%s" % (rel.through._meta.app_label, rel.through._meta.object_name)

        related_model = _related_model(rel)
        if isinstance(related_model, six.string_types):
            kwargs['to'] = related_model
        else:
            kwargs['to'] = '%s.%s' % (related_model._meta.app_label, related_model._meta.object_name)

        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        if VERSION < (1, 7):
            self.name = self.column = self.attname = name
        else:
            self.set_attributes_from_name(name)
        self.model = cls
        self.opts = cls._meta

        cls._meta.add_field(self)
        setattr(cls, name, self)
        if not cls._meta.abstract:
            # rel.to renamed to remote_field.model in Django 1.9
            if VERSION >= (1, 9):
                if isinstance(self.remote_field.model, six.string_types):
                    def resolve_related_class(cls, model, field):
                        field.remote_field.model = model
                    lazy_related_operation(
                        resolve_related_class, cls, self.remote_field.model, field=self
                    )
            else:
                if isinstance(self.rel.to, six.string_types):
                    def resolve_related_class(field, model, cls):
                        field.rel.to = model
                    add_lazy_relation(cls, self, self.rel.to, resolve_related_class)

            if isinstance(self.through, six.string_types):
                if VERSION >= (1, 9):
                    def resolve_related_class(cls, model, field):
                        self.through = model
                        self.remote_field.through = model
                        self.post_through_setup(cls)
                    lazy_related_operation(
                        resolve_related_class, cls, self.through, field=self
                    )
                else:
                    def resolve_related_class(field, model, cls):
                        self.through = model
                        _remote_field(self).through = model
                        self.post_through_setup(cls)
                    add_lazy_relation(
                        cls, self, self.through, resolve_related_class
                    )
            else:
                self.post_through_setup(cls)

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return 'ManyToManyField'

    def __lt__(self, other):
        """
        Required contribute_to_class as Django uses bisect
        for ordered class contribution and bisect requires
        a orderable type in py3.
        """
        return False

    def post_through_setup(self, cls):
        if RelatedObject is not None:  # Django < 1.8
            self.related = RelatedObject(cls, self.model, self)

        self.use_gfk = (
            self.through is None or issubclass(self.through, CommonGenericTaggedItemBase)
        )

        # rel.to renamed to remote_field.model in Django 1.9
        if VERSION >= (1, 9):
            if not self.remote_field.model:
                self.remote_field.model = self.through._meta.get_field("tag").remote_field.model
        else:
            if not self.rel.to:
                self.rel.to = self.through._meta.get_field("tag").rel.to

        if RelatedObject is not None:  # Django < 1.8
            self.related = RelatedObject(self.through, cls, self)

        if self.use_gfk:
            tagged_items = GenericRelation(self.through)
            tagged_items.contribute_to_class(cls, 'tagged_items')

        for rel in cls._meta.local_many_to_many:
            if rel == self or not isinstance(rel, TaggableManager):
                continue
            if rel.through == self.through:
                raise ValueError('You can\'t have two TaggableManagers with the'
                                 ' same through model.')

    def save_form_data(self, instance, value):
        getattr(instance, self.name).set(*value)

    def formfield(self, form_class=TagField, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            "label": capfirst(self.verbose_name),
            "help_text": self.help_text,
            "required": not self.blank
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return form_class(**defaults)

    def value_from_object(self, instance):
        if instance.pk:
            return self.through.objects.filter(**self.through.lookup_kwargs(instance))
        return self.through.objects.none()

    def related_query_name(self):
        return _model_name(self.model)

    def m2m_reverse_name(self):
        return _get_field(self.through, 'tag').column

    def m2m_reverse_field_name(self):
        return _get_field(self.through, 'tag').name

    def m2m_target_field_name(self):
        return self.model._meta.pk.name

    def m2m_reverse_target_field_name(self):
        # rel.to renamed to remote_field.model in Django 1.9
        if VERSION >= (1, 9):
            return self.remote_field.model._meta.pk.name
        else:
            return self.rel.to._meta.pk.name

    def m2m_column_name(self):
        if self.use_gfk:
            return self.through._meta.virtual_fields[0].fk_field
        return self.through._meta.get_field('content_object').column

    def db_type(self, connection=None):
        return None

    def m2m_db_table(self):
        return self.through._meta.db_table

    def bulk_related_objects(self, new_objs, using):
        return []

    def extra_filters(self, pieces, pos, negate):
        if negate or not self.use_gfk:
            return []
        prefix = "__".join(["tagged_items"] + pieces[:pos - 2])
        get = ContentType.objects.get_for_model
        cts = [get(obj) for obj in _get_subclasses(self.model)]
        if len(cts) == 1:
            return [("%s__content_type" % prefix, cts[0])]
        return [("%s__content_type__in" % prefix, cts)]

    def get_extra_join_sql(self, connection, qn, lhs_alias, rhs_alias):
        model_name = _model_name(self.through)
        if rhs_alias == '%s_%s' % (self.through._meta.app_label, model_name):
            alias_to_join = rhs_alias
        else:
            alias_to_join = lhs_alias
        extra_col = _get_field(self.through, 'content_type').column
        content_type_ids = [ContentType.objects.get_for_model(subclass).pk for
                            subclass in _get_subclasses(self.model)]
        if len(content_type_ids) == 1:
            content_type_id = content_type_ids[0]
            extra_where = " AND %s.%s = %%s" % (qn(alias_to_join),
                                                qn(extra_col))
            params = [content_type_id]
        else:
            extra_where = " AND %s.%s IN (%s)" % (qn(alias_to_join),
                                                  qn(extra_col),
                                                  ','.join(['%s'] *
                                                           len(content_type_ids)))
            params = content_type_ids
        return extra_where, params

    # This and all the methods till the end of class are only used in django >= 1.6
    def _get_mm_case_path_info(self, direct=False):
        pathinfos = []
        linkfield1 = _get_field(self.through, 'content_object')
        linkfield2 = _get_field(self.through, self.m2m_reverse_field_name())
        if direct:
            join1infos = linkfield1.get_reverse_path_info()
            join2infos = linkfield2.get_path_info()
        else:
            join1infos = linkfield2.get_reverse_path_info()
            join2infos = linkfield1.get_path_info()
        pathinfos.extend(join1infos)
        pathinfos.extend(join2infos)
        return pathinfos

    def _get_gfk_case_path_info(self, direct=False):
        pathinfos = []
        from_field = self.model._meta.pk
        opts = self.through._meta
        linkfield = _get_field(self.through, self.m2m_reverse_field_name())
        if direct:
            join1infos = [PathInfo(self.model._meta, opts, [from_field], _remote_field(self), True, False)]
            join2infos = linkfield.get_path_info()
        else:
            join1infos = linkfield.get_reverse_path_info()
            join2infos = [PathInfo(opts, self.model._meta, [from_field], self, True, False)]
        pathinfos.extend(join1infos)
        pathinfos.extend(join2infos)
        return pathinfos

    def get_path_info(self):
        if self.use_gfk:
            return self._get_gfk_case_path_info(direct=True)
        else:
            return self._get_mm_case_path_info(direct=True)

    def get_reverse_path_info(self):
        if self.use_gfk:
            return self._get_gfk_case_path_info(direct=False)
        else:
            return self._get_mm_case_path_info(direct=False)

    def get_joining_columns(self, reverse_join=False):
        if reverse_join:
            return ((self.model._meta.pk.column, "object_id"),)
        else:
            return (("object_id", self.model._meta.pk.column),)

    def get_extra_restriction(self, where_class, alias, related_alias):
        extra_col = _get_field(self.through, 'content_type').column
        content_type_ids = [ContentType.objects.get_for_model(subclass).pk
                            for subclass in _get_subclasses(self.model)]
        return ExtraJoinRestriction(related_alias, extra_col, content_type_ids)

    def get_reverse_joining_columns(self):
        return self.get_joining_columns(reverse_join=True)

    @property
    def related_fields(self):
        return [(_get_field(self.through, 'object_id'), self.model._meta.pk)]

    @property
    def foreign_related_fields(self):
        return [self.related_fields[0][1]]

    ...
```

taggit.models.py:

```
...
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class TagBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), unique=True, max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_('Slug'), unique=True, max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk and not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.slugify(self.name)
            from django.db import router
            using = kwargs.get("using") or router.db_for_write(
                type(self), instance=self)
            # Make sure we write to the same db for all attempted writes,
            # with a multi-master setup, theoretically we could try to
            # write and rollback on different DBs
            kwargs["using"] = using
            # Be oportunistic and try to save the tag, this should work for
            # most cases ;)
            try:
                with atomic(using=using):
                    res = super(TagBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                return res
            except IntegrityError:
                pass
            # Now try to find existing slugs with similar names
            slugs = set(
                self.__class__._default_manager
                .filter(slug__startswith=self.slug)
                .values_list('slug', flat=True)
            )
            i = 1
            while True:
                slug = self.slugify(self.name, i)
                if slug not in slugs:
                    self.slug = slug
                    # We purposely ignore concurrecny issues here for now.
                    # (That is, till we found a nice solution...)
                    return super(TagBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                i += 1
        else:
            return super(TagBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def slugify(self, tag, i=None):
        slug = default_slugify(unidecode(tag))
        if i is not None:
            slug += "_%d" % i
        return slug


class Tag(TagBase):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tags")
        app_label = 'taggit'
...
```

Comment: why not try rendering this as pure html, then you will know if this is a django or html problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the way HTML works; it converts any whitespace - including newlines - to spaces. If you don't want any spaces you will need to put everything on the same line.

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:post_list_by_tag' x.slug %}">{{ x.name }}</a>{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

```
{{ x.name.strip }}
```

Comment: Thank you but nothing changes

Comment: Could you post your Model?